# Is it possible to create a Visual Studio snippet which adds code explicitly in a class constructor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-snippets

I want to set up a code snippet (in this case in C#) to create a property which is additionally initialized in the class constructor, which includes that code is not only inserted in the class body but also explicitly in the constructor. Is that possible with just one snipped, and if yes: how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i've completely understood your question, but you can use this tool :


http://snippeteditor.codeplex.com/


You can write a snippet for a class which contains one property set in the class constructor

Take a look at the **class** and **prop** or **propfull** snippets, it should help you

Comment: the point is that the snippet should nut just create a property but also initialized it in the constructor. the mentioned snippets don't do that. but nice tip anyway, thanks!